# Play Framework: Impact of Jobs on the stateless model

Tags: playframework, job-scheduling

One of the great things about the Play framework is that it is fully stateless and only request/response-oriented. This is really nice since it allows me to deploy my app to the cloud and scale the number of play instances behind my load balancer without having to worry about state (session) replication...

Recently, however, I needed to execute some application logic outside of an HTTP request and found out that Play has the possibility to define Jobs which are fully managed by the framework. Sounds brilliant but it raises the question: how do these jobs fit into the stateless model that is used by Play?

Say I have a maintenance task that needs to run every hour and I define a scheduled job for that. If I then deploy multiple Play instances behind a load balancer, will that job be started at the same time on each instance? And if so, what would be a good approach to handle jobs that need to run "exclusively"?

I was thinking of creating a new play instance on a non-clustered server, re-using the JPA model of the existing (clustered) instance (and thus connecting to the same database). This new instance would contain only the maintenance jobs and since it's hosted on a non-clustered server, there is no risk of a job running simultaneously. At the same time, this would allow me to keep my existing, clustered instance completely stateless and easy to host / load balance. Would this be a good approach?

Comment: Starting a bounty, see below.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to cluster the job too. You could set a semaphore in the database to ensure that only one job is running. 
Another idea is to have a look at the Akka-Framework, which will be included in Play 2.0. I think it has build in mechanism with handle this problem, but I'm not sure. I haven't experiences with akka.

Answer (score 5):

As neils mentioned keeping a flag in the DB helps to find out if the job is already running. I use a db semaphore with other flags to give me the job status and extra info.

Another thing you could do is to use the Play.id to work out and define which instance should be running the jobs.
We use "play start --%prod", "play start --%prod1"... to start the apps and the following in my doJob() method:

```
doJob(){
   if ("prod".equalsIgnoreCase(Play.id)) {
   ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't really like the thought of locking my DB for this but I like your suggestion of checking which instance the job is running on!

Answer (score 2):

Having had a quick look into the source code of the Play Framework (classes `Job` and `JobsPlugin`) I think these are not suitable to use in a cluster environment when it's important that the Job only runs once per some time interval (without introduction of ugly hacks).

I see three possible solutions:

1. Use a job scheduler which supports clustering. The obvious choice is [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). Play also uses *parts* of Quartz (to parse the CRON expressions), but not the part which does the scheduling.
2. When using Play 2, possibly go for [Akka](http://akka.io/), which offers [a scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html).
3. Change your job such that it doesn't matter when it's being run twice (possible for some use cases).

Comment: Yeah, we're currently thinking about solution #1